# Determine material of Zener's diode based on its characteristics

Tags: voltage, diodes, zener

I have a plot log (I) = f(U) for a few diodes: Silicon diode, Germanium diode, some LED and a Zener diode. I need to determine the material, from which the Zener diode is made based on the positioning of its characteristics. What parameter should I look for to determine it? I thought about checking the band gap somehow, but I am not sure whether it can be determined by just having a plot log(I) = f(U).

And if I know the difference between voltages (for specified current) of two diodes , let's call them A and B, and I have some information about diode A (including its band gap), can I calculate the band gap of the B diode?

Comment: The material is **Silicon** not silicone

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but if you want to determine which of the four types of diodes you have you can look at the forward voltage (`V_f`) and reverse voltage when diode starts to conduct at reverse polarity (`V_r`) and maybe reverse leakage current (`I_rl`) before that point:

- Si-Diode: `V_f` ca. 0.6 V, large `V_r`, low Irl
- Ge-Diode: `V_f` ca. 0.3V, relative large `I_rl`
- LED: relative large `V_f` (> 1V, e.g. 1.4 V, depending on material)
- Si-Zener-Diode: `V_f` ca. 0.6V, `V_r` = `V_zener`

Comment: Would Germanium Zener Diode have V_f ca. 0.3 V or have I misunderstood your answer?

Comment: @Byakuya: Yes, I guess a Ge Zener-diode would have V_f ca. 0.3V. I have, however, never ever met a Ge-Zener diode (or a Zener diode made of anything else but Si).